# ORA-600[kdizoltp_getRowID: Reading beyond bitmapsize] error

Tags: oracle, compression

Recently our database got shutdown with the above error. Here is the [link](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=2452781.1) to oracle support document regarding this error which says that this problem happens with ADVANCED HIGH compression:

As a solution they suggest to recreate indexes without compression. But we couldn't find an actual reason why this occured and what caused that error. Simply removing compression would be a huge workload, since we have many objects compressed with Advanced High compression method in our data warehouse. Does that mean that Advanced high compression is not realiable method to use at all since it corrupts blocks?  Or is there more suitable and safe compression method to use in data warehouse systems?

Update: Here are screenshots from a trace file:

1.
[image]

2.
[image]

3.
[image]

Comment: ORA-600 errors should be resolved with the help of Oracle support as is is internal error which *should not* happen in everyday usage. It's hard to answer without enough investigation of the database traces

Comment: Are you sure the error actually shut down the database? That's an extremely rare kind of problem, and it's more likely that this ORA-600 bug breaks one session for one specific kind of query. If you can narrow down exactly how the problem occurs, there are likely other workarounds. Maybe you only need to avoid compression on one specific index, or avoid using the `PARALLEL_INDEX` hint on one index, or maybe you just need to rebuild the corrupt index one time, etc.

Comment: @JonHeller, thanks, DBA said trace files show a problem with one index that was compressed with advanced high compression. He dropped that index, and only then he could start the database. This problem has happened twice in 4 months now, so I am not sure when a compressed index becomes corrupt and it seems impossible to always keep an eye on indexes. Proposed solution was to remove compression from some tables. This could later raise a problem with storage, but we can at least add storage instead of having database down for 2 days

Comment: @Sherzodbek It still feels like there's more to this story. I've seen corrupt indexes before, but I'm struggling to understand how a single corrupt index can so thoroughly break the database. Was the index built in a system schema or the SYSTEM tablespace? Although the support document includes the same error message, this may be a different error. A bug that shuts down the database would almost certainly have a fix, not just a workaround. Next time this happens, I suggest *calling* Oracle, and demand a person troubleshoot the problem with you in real time and get to the root cause.

Comment: @JonHeller, I agree, this was a huge surprise for me too that one compressed index could cause such troubles. Regarding tablespace, no, the index was created on a different tablespace. I will update the question with screenshots of a trace file, for now we have removed compression for some tables. So far everything is stable, for future I will ask DBA to contact Oracle next time as you suggest